# Regex for Brazilian phone number

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I am attempting to setup a regex verification for a user to enter a Brazilian telephone number. The formats I would need it to accept (or as close as possible) would be:
`22-22222-2222` `22222222222` `(22) 22222 2222` `(22)-22222-2222` `22 22222 2222` `(22)222222222`

So it needs to accept numbers, spaces, dashes, parentheses only. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about `+` at start? And what is your code? How are you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: No I dont think we will need the + at the start. I currently have javascript verifying the input to meet certain validations. If the validation isnt met, the textbox goes red and the "Submit" button is greyed out. As it stands it has a regex that only allows for numeric values but the problem is when people try to add their own symbols, dashes, parenthesis the javascript validation keeps the box red and this confuses people apparently.

Comment: Then you should change your regex to accept not only numeric values, try this one: `\(?\d{2,}\)?[ -]?\d{4,}[\-\s]?\d{4}`, also check that your javascript constantly checks the format on some event, e.g. on the `<input onchange="yourcheck_function()">` or `input.oninput = function(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer came in the form of using the Jquery mask plugin. Was exactly what I needed and has much more functionality.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

`$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.input-telephone').mask('(99) 9999-9999?9');
        });`

Answer (score 8):

I just made a currently valid regex for Brazilian numbers:

```
^\s*(\d{2}|\d{0})[-. ]?(\d{5}|\d{4})[-. ]?(\d{4})[-. ]?\s*$
```

Check out the validation at https://regex101.com/r/safMl7/2

Will not get the country code, since we know it is from Brazil: +55.

Will work with the following examples, **with or without spaces and dashes**:

- 12 1234 1234
- 12 12345 1234
- 12345 1234
- 1234 1234

Each group of the regex will be divided by the correct brazilian grouping.

See this example: `62 98345 1234`

[image: See this example: 62 98345 1234]

Answer (score 3):

Mask for brasil Phone using javascript

regex for format 11 digits: `/(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2 $3-$4`

###### before no regex : `63991017575`

###### After aply regex: `(63) 9 9101-7575`

#### EXAMPLE 1 USING THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
var number = '63992017738';
number = number.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2 $3-$4")
```

Result: `(63) 9 9201-7738`

---

#### EXAMPLE 2 USING THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
var number = '63992017738';
number = number.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "$1 $2 $3-$4")
```

Result: `63 9 9101-7575`

---

#### EXAMPLE 3 USING THE JAVASCRIPT:

###### now + country code

```
//if you need this: +55 (63) 9 9201-7131
var number = '5563992017131';
number = number.toString().replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "+$1 ($2) $3 $4-$5")
```

Result: `+55 (63) 9 9201-7131`

---

Answer (score 2):

If you **always** have the area code (DDD), try a simplified version of [Frederiko's regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59556805).

```
^(\d{2})\D*(\d{5}|\d{4})\D*(\d{4})$
```

Check out at https://regex101.com/r/M1DrBo.

Answer (score 1):

What about this: `\(?\d{2,}\)?[ -]?\d{4,}[\-\s]?\d{4}`

Comment: It accepts infinite number or digits

Answer (score 0):

The following use of Regex seems to catch *around 20 of the most common ways to write a Brazilian phone number*. Fix and mobile numbers included.

```
(\b\(\d{2}\)\s?[9]?\s?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d\d{4})|(\b\d{2}\s?[9]?\s?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})|(\b([9]|[9]\s)?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})|(\b\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})
```

There are four "or" options to match a number. It goes from the more complex one (with parenthesis and DDD code) to the most simple one (i. e. eight digit phone number).

I added the `\b` in front and not in the end of each case because sometimes you can catch cases where people write a number followed by some description: "99000-1100word". You can remove the word boundaries as you want, though:

```
(\(\d{2}\)\s?[9]?\s?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d\d{4})|(\d{2}\s?[9]?\s?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})|(([9]|[9]\s)?\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})|(\d{4}(\-|\s)?\d{4})
```

Comment: I am sure many people can refine this regex and come with a more optimized version of it, but it solves all of my problems for this while.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplier

regex for 10 digits format: `(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})`

regex for 11 digits format: `(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})`

Therefore, you could write a function to regex and replace:

```
export function phoneFormatter10(phone) {
    phone = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); //remove all non digits
    return phone.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, "($1)$2-$3");

}

export function phoneFormatter11(phone) {
    phone = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); //remove all non digits
    return phone.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})/, "($1)$2-$3");
}
```

Examples of use:

```
phoneFormatter10('3499883424')
result: '(34)9988-3424'
phoneFormatter11('3499^883*4-244') //even with badly formatted string
result: '(34)99883-4244'
```